# How to show an image in notification which is coming from an app server using google cloud messaging in android

Tags: push-notifications

Link of image is coming from an app server but image is not shown on app in notification. How to resolve this problem? Please help me

Comment: This reads like a development question. This site is for _users_ of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here ([see the What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Development questions are on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).